# Zesty uses systemd or sysvinit, upstart

Tags: upstart, systemd

I'm looking at the [instructions](https://help.resilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206178924-Installing-Sync-package-on-Linux) for resilio-sync and trying to stop temporarily, this service (as it uses a port I need free for a project)

It offers instructions for systemd and for 'sysvinit, upstart'. I'm not sure which to use and, in any event, using `stop` with either of them still leaves the process running (using `ps aux`).

Which instructions *should* I follow?

What command will actually stop the process, in such a way that I can restart again without having to reboot?  (I tried `killall rslsync` before and ended up rebooting to get the sync back again)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty) uses systemd. See this [link](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2895517/ubuntu-just-switched-to-systemd-the-project-sparking-controversy-throughout-linux.html) so you should use the `systemctl` command. Ubuntu has been using systemd for a while now.